# Ignore deployment errors in PowerBuilder 8 Classic

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I am new to PowerBuilder having picked up a legacy project written in PowerBuilder 8 Classic.

I am in a position where I need to prove the handover project compiles and can be deployed.

I can perform a full build without any issue, but when I try and deploy, I get a handful of Unresolved DataWindow errors.

I don't appear to have the data objects in the project to resolve the errors but also do not want to just go ahead and delete the data windows (as the project is supposed to be in a deploy-able state).

Is there a way to deploy whilst ignoring these errors?

I understand that the errors will surface to the UI at some point, but I will be looking to resolve these, along with any other snags when I upgrade the project to PB 12.6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try marking all your libraries for PBD generation.

Edit: Since you've found my site, I'll point out that PBL Peeper has a "report" (PBR Builder Plus http://www.techno-kitten.com/PBL_Peeper/Online_Manual/Reports_Page/reports_page.html) that helps you create a single EXE deployment (no PBDs) while forcing the inclusion of all necessary objects.

Comment: Thanks @Terry. Just trying it now.

Comment: have learned something new. Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help. (btw: very useful website of yours)

Comment: Hi @Terry, I will take a look at PBL Peeper today.  With regard to marking all your libraries for PBD generation, what exactly does this do?  Does it still just create a single executable?

Comment: Don't worry. Have looked into the project painter a littler more and all is now making sense. Thanks for your help @Terry.